# Finding unofficial command line switches

Tags: windows, debugging, command-line, command-line-arguments, switch-statement

How can I go about finding out command line arguments for a given application? I know you can use `/?` and, if the app supports it, it'll display the switches, but is there a way to find 'unofficial' ones in a program?

Comment: I see it's been voted to close for not being constructive, but I don't understand what's wrong with the question.

Comment: What OS are we talking about? You can use `man <cmd>` on good ones...

Comment: Windows. I've updated the tags.

Comment: Why do you want to use undocumented command line options? They aren't documented for a reason. If you use them, then your program may stop working at any time.

Comment: Learning purposes. I'm interested in how people go about finding them. A Google search came up with various unofficial command line arguments for a program, but never explained how people found them.

Comment: Finding undocumented switches is often useful. For instance, if one is trying to create a login script that automatically installs a piece of software, sometimes they have a /silent switch. There is a freeware app out there called "Universal Silent Switch Finder" aka "USSF" that does this automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously google is the easiest answer... barring that... I don't think there is any special alternative to /? that will give you additional options. You might try running "strings" against the executable in question. That may spit out some hidden options. "strings" comes with most(all?) unix distributions, for windows: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439

If your not familiar with strings... it just spits out every string it can find inside an executable... it's often useful for finding hidden things.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't heard of Strings before. Google did give me the answer to the program in question, but I wanted to learn how the person actually managed to find them.

Answer (score 0):

For finding silent install switches, I found `Universal Silent Switch Finder 1.5.0.0` to be helpful. Because the original version is very old, I cannot find it on the original website, but softpedia has a download up: http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Universal-Silent-Switch-Finder-Download-180984.html